# WinSCP.SessionLocalException: The winscp.exe executable was not found at location of the assembly WinSCPnet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winscp, winscp-net

I am new working in a lab that sends data from a local computer to an HPC. I have been all day working around the following problem I am not familiar with it at all.

```
4/19/2022 3:21:28 PM ERROR: WinSCP.SessionLocalException: The winscp.exe executable was not found at location of the assembly WinSCPnet (C:\WRGLPipeline\WRGLPipeline\bin\dlls), nor the entry assembly WRGLPipeline (C:\WRGLPipeline\WRGLPipeline\bin), nor in an installation path. You may use Session.ExecutablePath property to explicitly set path to winscp.exe.
   at WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess.GetExecutablePath()
   at WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess..ctor(Session session, Boolean useXmlLog, String additionalArguments)
   at WinSCP.Session.Open(SessionOptions sessionOptions)
   at WRGLPipeline.PanelPipelineWrapper.ConnectToIridis()
   at WRGLPipeline.PanelPipelineWrapper.UploadAndExecute()
   at WRGLPipeline.PanelPipelineWrapper.ExecutePanelPipeline()
   at WRGLPipeline.Programme.Main(String[] args)
```

As far I have been reading in documentation and forums everything is ok in my directories but I would like to ensure this as I am practically new working on Windows machines.

This is the structure of my `bin` folder

```
.
├── WRGLPipeline.exe
├── WRGLPipeline.exe.config
├── WRGLPipeline.ini
├── dlls
│   ├── CommandLine.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
│   ├── Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
│   ├── System.Buffers.dll
│   ├── System.Memory.dll
│   ├── System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
│   ├── System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
│   ├── System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
│   ├── System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
│   ├── System.ValueTuple.dll
│   └── WinSCPnet.dll
└── keys
    ├── nhs.key
    └── soton.key
```

As far I can see the executable is in the `bin` folder. Now I am looking at this from home, do I need to leave a copy of my executable in the `dlls` folder? Following the error message, If I need to specify the `Session.ExecutablePath`, where should this be?

These is the files before compiling the application

```
├── AuxillaryFunctions.cs
├── Coverage.cs
├── FileManagement.cs
├── GenerateGenotypingVCFs.cs
├── GenotypingPipelineWrapper.cs
├── Manual
│   └── WRGLPipeline-Manual.md
├── MyeloidPipelineWrapper.cs
├── PanelPipelineWrapper.cs
├── ParseArgs.cs
├── ParseBED.cs
├── ParseSampleSheet.cs
├── ParseVCF.cs
├── Programme.cs
├── ProgrammeParameters.cs
├── Properties
│   └── AssemblyInfo.cs
├── Static
│   ├── PipelineInterface.exe
│   ├── WRGLPipeline.ini
│   └── WRGL_logo.ico
├── WRGLPipeline.csproj
├── WRGLPipeline.csproj.user
├── app.config
└── packages.config
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommandLineParser" version="2.8.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" version="3.1.9" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WinSCP" version="5.17.10" targetFramework="net47" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you believe the error refers to the `.exe` of your application (`WRGLPipeline.exe`). It does not. It refers to `WinSCP.exe`. WinSCP .NET assembly `WinSCPnet.dll` needs `WinSCP.exe` binary to work.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#installing

The easiest solution is using [WinSCP NuGet package](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget) that includes both binaries.